# Pod route in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any possibility to create a service which is able to route traffic to selected pod(not pod group).

Example: myservice.whatever:1000/podNameAppName to route to custom pod ?

Comment: You should take a look at headless services or statefulsets, they allow you to query pods by their IP/DNS name.  A similar question was asked recently, you should look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007073/how-to-route-to-specific-pod-through-kubernetes-service-like-a-gateway-api/58018024#58018024

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Alassane Ndiaye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007073/how-to-route-to-specific-pod-through-kubernetes-service-like-a-gateway-api/58018024#58018024) for internal routing.
In addition if this question is related to the external requests you should create more advanced application design.

Please take a look for ADC concept like [NGINX ADC](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/application-delivery-controller/), [ISTIO Design Pattern](https://containerjournal.com/topics/container-networking/service-mesh-is-not-a-product-its-a-design-pattern/) and [ADC overview](https://www.trustradius.com/application-delivery-controllers-adc).

Basically this task should be implemented at higher level using all benefits from L7 loadbalncing support.

Please take a look also for K8s [concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)
Hope this help.